# How to make GPSD work as server?

Tags: command-line, gps

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to make gpsd work as sever. [Documentation here](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/index.html#documentation).

I use `service --status-all` to see the list:

```
...
 [ - ]  checkroot-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot.sh
 [ + ]  console-setup
 [ + ]  cron
 [ - ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  gdm3
 ----------------
 [ - ]  gpsd  
 ----------------
 [ + ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hostname.sh
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ - ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.dpkg-bak
 [ - ]  killprocs
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  lm-sensors
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ + ]  lvm2-lvmetad
 [ + ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ - ]  mountall-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  mountall.sh
....
```

Gpsd shows `[ - ]`, as it's inactive. Now, I want to make it `[ + ]`.

I read and asked [How to Stop GPSD daemon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894725/how-to-stop-gpsd-daemon) but I now need help on how to start/activate the process/daemon gpsd.

Comment: Can you point out which section of the documentation are you following exactly?

Comment: @M.Becerra : thanks for coming back, http://askubuntu.com/questions/4879/what-do-the-symbols-in-service-status-all-mean , http://askubuntu.com/questions/624632/why-does-my-init-d-script-show-up-under-status-all-but-i-cant-otherwise-cont

Comment: No, I mean, the documentation to *make GPSD work as server*. I assume, somewhere over here http://www.catb.org/gpsd/index.html#documentation

Comment: Let me see the `terminal` output of `cat /etc/default/gpsd` and `sudo service gpsd status`. Edit the output into your original question, not the comments please.

Comment: Oh, hello again. What changed from the time that we had it working? Also, I asked that you not use the comments to post that output. It's very difficult to cull all the information that way. Please delete those last 2 comments, and edit that output into your original question.

Comment: @heynnema: oh, I read the conversation between you and "phucnguyen" regarding to the gpsmon, xgps activation. I tried to delete output but they did not let me do it, limited time to edit. it's very helpful for me, so I remember you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/891662/why-does-cgps-s-give-me-no-results

Comment: Refresh my memory... do you have a link for the conversation with phucnguyen? What changed from the time we had it running? To delete the comments with the terminal output, just click the little x icon that follows each comment... then redo the commands and edit them into your original question so they're readable.

Comment: @heynnema: just did it, I hope you will remember. Maybe this question will be different.

Comment: I don't see what you "just did it"... and I still don't have answers for 1) what changed since the time we had it running, and 2) tell me the link for my conversation with phucnguyen so I can review it. I'll put together a quick answer for what I believe that you're asking... give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: @heynnema: I just delete all the output on comments, and here is the conversation b/w you and him: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55172/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-why-does-cgps-s-give-me-no-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start/stop/restart gpsd:

```
sudo systemctl start gpsd
sudo systemctl stop gpsd
sudo systemctl restart gpsd
```

To manage the gpsd.service alone:

```
sudo service gpsd start
sudo service gpsd stop
sudo service gpsd restart
sudo service gpsd status
```

Comment: The commands you gave me are my expectations. Thank you.

Comment: since I "stop" it, it seems work since I run this command **"gpsd -D 5 -N -n /dev/ttyACM0"**  follow the instruction from this link http://www.catb.org/gpsd/installation.html

Comment: You're forgetting that you have the gpsd.service running while you manually issue a "gpsd -D 5 -N -n /dev/ttyACM0" command. That command runs gpsd in the foreground. If gpsd.service is running already, then you're trying to run it twice, once in the background, and once in the foreground... that's why the stop command allows it to work.

Comment: can I ask you one more question? why in the NMEA message sometime have this message? **gpsmon:ERROR: KPPS:/dev/ttyACM0 kernel PPS failed Connection timed out** beside the good NMEA messages( RMC, GGA, ....)

Comment: Are you plugged into a USB3 port?

Comment: yes, I am. USB3 port is using most of the time for my situation.

Comment: Try using a USB2 port and see if the error message goes away.

Comment: still have same problem.

Comment: I don't know then.